# trying to change str to int with strtol, but it gives different value

Tags: c

My input file looks like this:

```
Harry potter
9403133410 // his ID (this number changes to different one)
```

Here is the code:

```
void get(){
    FILE* file;
    int i = 0;
    char load[50];
    long x;
    char *nac;
    file = fopen("konferencny_zoznam.txt", "r");
    while (fgets(load, sizeof load, subor) != NULL){
        if (i == 0){
            printf("Prezenter: %s", load);
        }
        if (i == 1){
            x = strtol(load, &nac, 15); //trying to change 9403133410 to int, but it gives me different value
            printf("%ld", x);
            printf("Rodne Cislo: %s", load);
        }
        if (i == 2){
            printf("Kod prezentacnej miestnosti: %s", load);
        }
        if (i == 3){
            printf("Nazov prispevku: %s", load);
        }
        if (i == 4){
            printf("Mena autorov: %s", load);
        }
        if (i == 5){
            printf("Typ prezentovania: %s", load);
        }
        if (i == 6){
            printf("Cas prezentovania: %s", load);
        }
        if (i == 7){
            printf("Datum: %s", load);
        }
        if (i == 8){
            printf("\n");
        }
        i++;
        if (i == 9){i = 0;}
        }
}
```

I need that integer to create an error, if for example ID cannot be divisible by 2 or 6.

Comment: The result is most likely too large to fit into an `int`.  Also, did you really intend to use base 15?  That would make it even larger than if it were in base 10.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. This includes a function `main` and all `#include` directives. That way, you make it easier for other people to reproduce the problem.

Comment: What @TomKarzes means is that the `15` in `strtol(load, &nac, 15)` means "the string to convert is in base 15"

Comment: _Side note:_ You can replace the multiple `if` statements with a single `switch`. (e.g.) `switch (i) { case 0: printf("Prezenter: %s", load); break; case 1: x = strtol(load, &nac, 10); printf("%ld", x); printf("Rodne Cislo: %s", load); break; }`

Comment: @CraigEstey thank you for answer, i tried this, but now i ended up with showing Prezenter at start of every line.

Comment: At a guess ... You can put cases 0-8 in the `switch`, but after the switch's closing `}`, you [still] _need_ the `if` as in: `if (++i == 9) i = 0;` to force the increment of `i` on each loop???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
x = strtol(load, &nac, 15);
```

First, this is reading a number as base 15.  Assuming you actually want base 10, this should be:

```
x = strtol(load, &nac, 10);
```

Next, 9403133410b10 is too large to fit in a 32 bit integer.  `long` is not guaranteed to be larger than that (and on Windows it's not), so you should use `long long` instead.  You'll also need to call `strtoll` to read it and use `%lld` to print it.

```
long long x;
...

x = strtoll(load, &nac, 10);
printf("%lld", x);
```